# How to call a function with arguments onclick of a button in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my function with arguments that i added in index.html in publics folder in a script tag

```
function displayContent(event, contentNameID) {

    let content = document.getElementsByClassName("contentClass");
    let totalCount = content.length;

    for (let count = 0; count < totalCount; count++) {
        content[count].style.display = "none";
    }

    let links = document.getElementsByClassName("linkClass");
    totalLinks = links.length;
    for (let count = 0; count < totalLinks; count++) {
        links[count].classList.remove("active");
    }

    document.getElementById(contentNameID).style.display = "block";
    event.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
}
```

Trying to call this function from click of buttons on my react component that looks like below

```
<button class="linkClass" onclick="displayContent(event, 'project2')">Meet at Campus
</button>
```

Please guide me with the syntax

Comment: You could do this onClick={(event) => displayContent(event, 'project2')}

Comment: That's not how React works. You shouldn't be using native DOM methods. You need to maintain state, and when that change the component will render again with new JSX derived from that state. That's also not a React component.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the correct syntax

```
<button className="linkClass" onClick={(event)=>displayContent(event,'project2')}>Meet at Campus</button>
```

Edit: please note that React components return [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to make some sort accordion but you shouldn't really be mixing vanilla JS with React as React needs control of the DOM.

So here's a brief example of how you might approach this using 1) state, and 2) a `Panel` component which comprises a button, and some content.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // Initialise state with an array of false values
  const [ state, setState ] = useState([
    false, false, false
  ]);

  // When a button in a panel is clicked get
  // its id from the dataset, create a new array using `map`
  // and then set the new state (at which point the component
  // will render again
  function handleClick(e) {
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    const updated = state.map((el, i) => {
      if (i === id - 1) return true;
      return false;
    });
    setState(updated);
  }

  // Pass in some props to each Panel component
  return (
    <div>
      
      <Panel
        name="Panel 1"
        active={state[0]}
        id="1"
        handleClick={handleClick}
      >
        <span className="text1">Content 1</span>
      </Panel>
      
      <Panel
        name="Panel 2"
        active={state[1]}
        id="2"
        handleClick={handleClick}
      >
        <span className="text2">Content 2</span>
      </Panel>
      
      <Panel
        name="Panel 3"
        active={state[2]}
        id="3"
        handleClick={handleClick}
      >
        <span className="text3">Content 3</span>
      </Panel>
    
    </div>
  );

}

function Panel(props) {
  
  // Destructure those props
  const {
    name,
    id,
    active,
    handleClick,
    children
  } = props;
  
  // Return a div with a button, and
  // content found in the children prop
  // When the button is clicked the handler is
  // called from the parent component, the state
  // is updated, a new render is done. If the active prop
  // is true show the content otherwise hide it
  return (
    <div className="panel">
      <button data-id={id} onClick={handleClick}>
        {name}
      </button>
      <div className={active && 'show'}>
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.panel button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.panel { margin: 1em 0; }
.panel div { display: none; }
.panel div.show { display: block; margin: 1em 0; }
.add { margin-top: 1em; background-color: #44aa77; }
.text1 { color: darkblue; font-weight: 600; }
.text2 { color: darkgreen; font-weight: 700; }
.text3 { color: darkred; font-weight: 300; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Can't you use

```
document.getElementById("linkClass").onclick = () =>{
    displayContent();
}
```

by giving the element an id with same of the class?

Comment: The question is about _React_ not vanilla JS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).